# understanding javascript/jquery events: why does this alert fire four times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have basic feel for using javascript and jquery and want to understand what exactly is going on when an event fires.

This code generates FOUR alerts that say "submitButton." Why is that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'/>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
               $(document).ready(function () {
                         $("*").click(function(event) {
                            alert(event.target.id);
                        });
               });
        </script>

    <body>


        <div id='submitDiv'>
        <input id='submitButton' type="submit" class="button" value="Submit"/>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read about "Event Propagation".

Comment: some other good reading http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: The * indicates all elements. You can `console.log` to see what exactly is being selected but basically you are attaching click event handlers to everything and each of them is firing the event you have attached.

Comment: Instead of logging the `event.target.id`, log `this.nodeName`. http://jsfiddle.net/c7jSf/

Comment: or `event.currentTarget`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `*` literal selects all elements.  So you're adding a handler to:

1. document (html)
2. body
3. submitDiv
4. submitButton

Note that events bubble (bottom up to the top of the DOM).  You can prevent the event bubbling by returning false from a handler:

```
$("*").click(function(event) {
    alert(event.target.id);
    return false;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PD7aM/8/)

Comment: why does the alert say "submitButton" four times and not  
submitButton, submitDiv, body, document (html)

Comment: @abe3 Then you should do `alert(this.id)` instead of `alert(event.target.id)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code attaches a click handler to all elements and because the event propagates up, it will hit all click handlers from `<input>` all the way up to `document`.

> why does the alert say "submitButton" four times?

This is because you're referencing `event.target` which always points to the first clicked element. If you want to show a different id for each element in the propagation you need to reference `this`, i.e.:

```
alert(this.id);
```

You can stop propagation by either returning `false` from your click handler or explicitly via the `event` object:

```
$('*').on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert(event.target.id);
});
```

This is not recommended though, because having all those event handlers take up memory. It would be better to use event delegation.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', function(event) {
        console.log(event.target);
    });
});
```